# avcodec_decode_video2 always sets got_picture_ptr to 0 while using with live555

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec, live555, avcodec

I am trying to decode frames using libavcodec. My applications retrieves rtp packets from on rtsp stream using live555. I have searched quite a lot for reasons of avcodec_decode_video setting got_picture_ptr to 0 but haven't been able to find it.
  Can anyone tell me how avcodec_decode_video2 works internally? What reasons might lead the got_picture_ptr pointer to be set to zero? 
PS: The function does read bytes i.e the return value is always a positive number, not -1.
I'm stumped here, any help would be appreciated. I haven't quoted any code since the code to decode using avcodec_decode_video2 is fairly generic and there is nothing special in my code.(I have decoded rtsp streams earlier using libavcodec, just not along with live555)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was finally able to solve it. The problem was the way I handled the MediaSink object from live555. I was supposed to call the afterGettingFrame function of the Sink class that I had derived from MediaSink which I wasn't doing because of which although I was getting the data, I wasn't 'reading' the data and feeding it into avcodec_decode_video2 method.